# web scraping with BeautifulSoup and python

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm triyng to print out all the Ip address from this website https://hidemy.name/es/proxy-list/#list

but nothing happens

code in python 2.7:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def trade_spider(max_pages): #go throw max pages of the website starting from 1
    page = 0
    value = 0
    print('proxies')
    while page <= 18:
        value += 64
        url = 'https://hidemy.name/es/proxy-list/?start=' + str(value) + '#list' #add page number to link
        source_code = requests.get(url) #get website html code
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')

        for link in soup.findAll('td',{'class': 'tdl'}): #get the link of this class
            proxy = link.string #get the string of the link
            print(proxy)

        page += 1

trade_spider(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seeing any output because there is no matching elements in your soup.
I've tried to dump all the variables to output stream and figured out that this website is blocking crawlers. Try to print plain_text variable. It'll probably only contain warning message like:

> It seems you are bot. If so, please use separate API interface. It 
>   cheap and easy to use.